# closing socket after forcing terminal close

Tags: bluetooth, socket

I'm running Bluetooth socket server, this server is listening to incoming connection. but I forced the terminal close ctrl + Z . after that the server is not listeing any more and show me the output `accepted connection from 00:00:00:00:00:00`

to make it run again I should restart my computer. how can I close properly the socket to I  can run the server again without reboot

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = { 0 }, rem_addr = { 0 };
    char buf[1024] = { 0 };
    int s, client, bytes_read;
    socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);
    s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);
    loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = *BDADDR_ANY;
    loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));
    listen(s, 1);
    client = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);
    ba2str( &rem_addr.rc_bdaddr, buf );
    fprintf(stderr, "accepted connection from %s\n", buf);
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    bytes_read = read(client, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if( bytes_read > 0 ) {
        printf("received [%s]\n", buf);
    }
    close(client);
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to handle signals and close the socket in a callback function (when a Ctrl+Z is detected for example) [This](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html#Basic-Signal-Handling) page can help you !